# Why can't this mixer be built with two resistors?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, mixer

Disclosure: This is for the MIT Circuits MOOC on edX.

The task says build a circuit such that Vout ~= 1/2 V1 + 1/6 V2. Now I understand the solution, which uses three resistors.

However, I'd like to understand why it can't be done with two resistors.

For example, if it was modelled like this (but with the top resistor R2 and the bottom R1):

[image]

Then, by using superposition, can't you say:

Vout = aV1 + bV2 where a and b are some coefficients by reference to the resistors.

Then you could make a = R2/(R1+R2) = 1/2, and b = R1/(R1+R2) = 1/6 ? And solve for R1 and R2. I know those two simultaneous equations can't be solved, but I don't understand why and how that fits into the theory of the circuit.

Comment: The voltage across the resistors is the **difference** between V1 and V2. With no third resistor to reference this point to ground the voltage at the junction of R and R is simply half way between these two voltages. These are fixed resistance values so you **can't get two different ratios**.

Comment: Assume V1 > V2 (could be swapped if desired) A two resistor circuit has one end at V1 and the other end at V2. The mid point MUST be >= V2 and <= V1. It CANNOT be BELOW V2 as nothing it is connected to is < V2. | If eg V1 >= 2 x V2 then you can satisfy the 1/2 x V1 requirement but as all points are > V2 you CANNOT get any V < V2.

Comment: A "mixer" is a nonlinear device commonly used in RF transceivers. What you're describing is an "adder".

Answer (score 7):

Think about it - what happens when there isn't a third resistor (to 0 volts) and both input voltages are (say) 10 volts - the output will be 10 volts irrespective of what you have set R1 and R2 to be i.e. it doesn't work without a third resistor. Maybe there are some exceptions but generally, it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @anda-aka but why is it independent of R1 and R2? And how did you reach that the output would be 10 volts?

Comment: If you have two voltage sources of 10 volts and connect them to each other via 1 Gohm (or 1 ohm or 1 Tohm or any value) resistors, the junction of the resistors will still be 10 volts. How can it be anything other than 10 volts because there is no third resistor to ground. Even if the resistors are of different value, you'll still get 10 volts at the junction.

Answer (score 4):

As you've already found out:

$$
a = \frac {R_2} {R_1+R_2} \\
b = \frac {R_1} {R_1+R_2}
$$

Also realise that:

$$
a + b = \frac {R_2} {R_1+R_2} + \frac {R_1} {R_1+R_2} = 1
$$

So \$a\$ and \$b\$ are tightly coupled: once you choose the value for \$a\$ by selecting \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, then the value of \$b\$ gets set as well. In other words: **2 resistors only give you one degree of freedom**, whereas you need 2 degrees of freedom in order to set \$a\$ and \$b\$ independently.

And how can you introduce the additional degree of freedom you need? With an additional resistor \$R_3\$ connected to ground so that:

$$
a = \frac {R_2 || R_3} {R_1 + (R_2 || R_3)} \\
b = \frac {R_1 || R_3} {R_2 + (R_1 || R_3)}
$$

This is the resulting circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fehiOnm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, \$a\$ and \$b\$ are not as tightly coupled as before. Thanks to resistor \$R_3\$ you can select values for \$a\$ and \$b\$ other than those that give \$a+b=1\$. Now the problem is reduced to solve for \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$, so that you get your desired \$a\$ and \$b\$.

### An alternative look at the problem:

Another way to look at this is as follows.

You have 2 voltage sources \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$ connected to a common node through resistors \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$. Then, the voltage at the common node is a weighted average of voltages \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$, in the form \$V_{out}=aV_1+bV_2\$. You can change the resistor to set the weights \$a\$ and \$b\$, but the sum of the weights must be 1, \$a+b=1\$.

Now we introduce a third voltage source, so you have 3 voltage sources \$V_1\$, \$V_2\$ and \$V_3\$ connected to a common node through resistors \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$. Again, the voltage at the common node is a weighted average of voltages \$V_1\$, \$V_2\$ and \$V_3\$, in the form \$V_{out}=aV_1+bV_2+cV_3\$. You can change the resistor to set the weights \$a\$, \$b\$ and \$c\$, but the sum of the weights must be 1 again, \$a+b+c=1\$.

However, in this case we can set the third source to 0V, which is the same as connecting \$R_3\$ to ground. Then the output will not depend on coefficient \$c\$, i.e. \$V_{out}=aV_1+bV_2\$. You have the same expression of the previous case, but with an extra degree of freedom, because now \$a+b=1-c\$ instead of \$a+b=1\$. Thus, you can adjust the value of c in order to get the values of \$a\$ and \$b\$ that you need.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct. It might be easier to understand if you can first satisfy yourself that the coefficients of V1 and V2 in the equation for Vout must total 1, if only 2 resistors are used. In the task they don't, so the third resistor lets the total be some smaller value.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSSbWw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As pointed out by Andy the values of the resistors in this circuit are not relevant if \$V_1 = V_2\$ \$V_{out} \$ will be the same as \$V_1 \$ or \$V_2 \$.

The output will always be somewhere between \$V_1 \$ and \$V_2 \$.

If you apply Kirchoff's current law that the net current into a node is zero, or to put it another way, in this case the current flowing into 'out' via \$ R_1 \$ must equal the current flowing out via \$ R_2 \$ we can easily prove.

$$out = \dfrac{\dfrac{V_1}{R_1}+\dfrac{V_2}{R_2}}{\dfrac{1}{R_1}+\dfrac{1}{R_2}} = \dfrac{V_1 \cdot R_2 + V_2 \cdot R_1}{R_1+R_2}$$

So we are looking for in order to solve your example

\$ \dfrac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \$ so \$ R_2 = R_1 \$

and

\$ \dfrac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} = \dfrac{1}{6} \$ so \$ R_2 = 5 \cdot R_1 \$

These obviously can't both be true which is why you need the third resistor to 0V.

---

**Edit: Extending this answer**

If we add a third resistor we have extended the range of \$ a \$ and \$ b \$ available but we are still limited on what ratios are available.

Without \$ R_3 \$ then \$ a = \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} \$ and \$ b = \dfrac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} \$ Giving:

$$ a + b = \dfrac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} + \dfrac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} = \dfrac{R_1+R_2}{R_1+ R_2} = 1$$

Since \$ \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{6} = \dfrac{2}{3} \neq 1 \$ What you want is not possible.

Adding in \$ R_3 \$ from out to 0V we have

$$
\begin{align}
out = & \dfrac{\dfrac{V_1}{R_1}+\dfrac{V_2}{R_2}}{\dfrac{1}{R_1}+\dfrac{1}{R_2}+\dfrac{1}{R_3}} \\
   = & \dfrac{\dfrac{V_1 \cdot R_2 + V_2 \cdot R_1}{R_1 \cdot R_2}}{\dfrac{R_1 \cdot R_2+ R_1 \cdot R_3 + R_2 \cdot R_3}{R_1 \cdot R_2 \cdot R_3}} \\
= & \dfrac{V_1 \cdot R_2 + V_2 \cdot R_2}{R_1 + R2 + \dfrac{R_1 \cdot R_2}{R_3}}
\end{align}
$$

Giving

\$ a = \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2 + \dfrac{R_1 \cdot R_2}{R_3}} \$ and \$ b = \dfrac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2 + \dfrac{R_1 \cdot R_2}{R_3}} \$

A moments thought should convince you that \$ 0 \le a + b \lt 1 \$

How do we choose \$ R_1 \$, \$ R_2 \$ and \$ R_3 \$?

\$ R_2 = \dfrac{a}{b} \cdot R_1 \$

and

\$ R_3 = \dfrac{a}{1 - (a+b)} \cdot R_1\$